# Should golden badges be awarded with some rep points?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

Would it be a good idea to also reward users with rep points when they unlock a new golden badge?

Access to 100% of the moderation tools only happens at 10k points. Scoring that amount of rep is hard and takes time, reflecting the commitment of a user toward the community.

As many of you are aware, the FAQ states that access to the previous level of moderation is achieved at 3k points, and going from 3k to 10k is a really LONG LONG way.

Since golden badges also represent a higher commitment to the community and can be very difficult to get, I wonder if we should also reward a user with rep points (300? 400? 500?) to help him on his journey.

What do you think?

Comment: -1 Why? Bad formulated question? I'm not sure its OK to down vote just because you don't agree with my suggestion.

Comment: @karlphilip but that is how Meta works. Disagreement = downvote. It's not like on SO proper

Comment: @Pekka Just upvote some answer you agree with. No harm done.

Comment: @karlphillip: Try not to conflate downvoting with malice ("harm"). It is useful to treat rep as a semi-random integer, given to you by a stranger. Downvotes on meta don't mean "I don't like *you*"; they could mean "this is not a good idea".

Comment: @Gamecat It's not since I'm not suggesting awarding points along with each badge.

Comment: I wish I'd seen these comments on Day 1 because it would have made Stack Meta WAY less intimidating to me than it's been :) Makes me wonder if there's a way to get this added to the FAQ, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a heck of a lot easier to amass 10k rep than get most of the gold badges (and of those that can be got before, they're *difficult* and time-consuming). Just make helpful and thoughtful answers and you'll climb the mountain; the accelerated route is to compete for bounties. There's no need to make badges give out “monetary” awards.

That said, if there's points being given out for gold badges, there should be something for the lower badge levels too (e.g., so that there's 1 rep for bronze, 10 for silver, 50 for gold) to form a full system. Like that it would give a small boost but won't distort the requirement for *experience* at the lower levels before granting access to the advanced capabilities.

Answer (score 13):

They already get a golden badge as a reward for whatever they did. I don't think there needs to be an additional reward for receiving a reward.

Comment: ☢ "This reward was brought to you from the department of redundancy rewardments."

Answer (score 2):

I agree, but would it be fair to reward the user with only 500 points? It doesn't seem much, especially since - like you said - gold badges are very difficult to get.

Maybe along with the 500 rep reward, the user could be awarded an additional gold badge too.

Comment: Huh? So award a gold badge for earning a gold badge?

Comment: @animuson I think a little bit of crossover weren't surely bad, because it induced additional motivation. Only the eigenvalues of the crossover matrix should remain far below 1. In laymans terms, the reputation which we get for a golden badge shouldn't be enough to get an additional golden badge, even the comulated effects of the whole cross-reward spectrum shouldn't be enough to induce infinite loops. The real activity could be easily calculated by a simple matrix inversion.

Comment: @animuson and 5 other people... *whooooosh*.